# Samsung Emulator missing Google API - Maps?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, galaxy-tab

Our app uses the Googe API for maps.

When we try and run the app on the emulator provided by `Samsung for their Galaxy`, it fails because it seems that the emulator is `missing the shared library`? How can this be overcome?

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

Here's the configuration of the AVD:

[image]

Comment: you have google api level - 8 ?

Comment: Create emulator from google api versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Google APIs(Google Inc.)-API Level 8

as Galaxy Tab Addon system image do not include the Maps external library`(com.google.android.maps)`.